# MySQL Installer Closes without any Effect

Tags: mysql

When I try to install MySQL on my Windows machine. The installer runs and the following progress bar appears then it closes right away without any effect.

[image: MySQL Installer]

Comment: Have you tried [looking into the error log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-troubleshooting.html) ?

Comment: I checked the folders mentioned in the article but I found no my.ini file. I found another mydefault.ini file which does not contain any informative log.

Comment: I can't give you any advice other than the link, because this has never happened to me.  Maybe some MySQL guru can help you +1.

Comment: That's ok. Thanks for trying to help anyway...

Comment: I found out this happens with many installers on this PC and not just MySQL. I am guessing it's either a Windows issue or a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and thankfully I solved it.

Basically your installer already opened a window when it finished loading but somehow the window is hidden. You can open the window via task manager